# pass param to sub_classed format_coord in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, instance, subclass, interactive

I followed a tutorial in Benjamin Root's book "Interactive applications using Matplotlib" to subclass the format_coord() method of a matplotlib image axes. It works. I have a gui application in which main.py imports the data pointer and uses it to change the interactive numbers displayed when I move the mouse over the image.

```
from gui_stuff.datapointer import DataPointerLeftCart
```

and then it is used by calling:

```
self.ax_lhs = self.f_lhs.add_subplot(111,projection = 'sp_data_pointer')
```

the stripped down code for DataPointerLeftCart is defined as follows in a separate file:

```
import matplotlib.projections as mproj
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Our own modules
from operations.configurations import configParser

class DataPointerLeftCart(Axes):
    name = 'sp_data_pointer'
    def format_coord(self, y, z):
        configparams = configParser(ConfigFile=configfilename)        
        centreY = float(configparams['CENTRE_Y'])#units are pixels
        scale = float(configparams['SCALE'])#nm^-1 per pixel

    new_qy = (y-(centreY))*scale

    return "Qy: %f (nm^-1)" % (new_qy)

mproj.projection_registry.register(DataPointerLeftPol)
```

configParser() is a function that reads a text file and creates a dictionary with various important configuration numbers for my program. Originally this had no arguments and configParser specified the location of the text file but recently I have modified the entire program so that you specify a local copy of the configuration file. This requires me to be able to pass a configfilename argument. However, I'm confused about how to do this. The configfilename must come from main.py but here I only give the name 'sp_data_pointer' as an argument to the add_subplot.

This is confusing me since there is nowhere (visibly within my code) where I create an instance of the class and presumably the "**init**" method is taken care of inside Axes which I am subclassing. Could someone explain the principles and /or a dirty workaround to get me moving (preferable both!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but it could well be that the `format_coord` method is not actually used in any way at the Axes initialization. This would open the possibility to set the `configfilename` after creation. To this end, one could make the configfilename a class variable and define a setter for it.

```
class DataPointerLeftCart(Axes):
    name = 'sp_data_pointer'
    configfilename = None

    def format_coord(self, y, z):
        configparams = configParser(ConfigFile=self.configfilename)        
        centreY = float(configparams['CENTRE_Y'])#units are pixels
        scale = float(configparams['SCALE'])#nm^-1 per pixel
        new_qy = (y-(centreY))*scale
        return "Qy: %f (nm^-1)" % (new_qy)

    def set_config_filename(self,fname):
        self.configfilename = fname
```

Then call the setter after creation.

```
self.ax_lhs = self.f_lhs.add_subplot(111,projection = 'sp_data_pointer')
self.ax_lhs.set_config_filename("myconfigfile.config")
```

I have to admit I feel a bit strange about subclassing `Axes` just for setting the format.

So an alternative could be not to subclass `Axes` but to use the format_coord inside the main.py:

```
from operations.configurations import configParser
configfilename = "myconfigfile.config"

def format_coord(y, z):
    configparams = configParser(ConfigFile=configfilename)        
    centreY = float(configparams['CENTRE_Y'])#units are pixels
    scale = float(configparams['SCALE'])#nm^-1 per pixel
    new_qy = (y-(centreY))*scale
    return "Qy: %f (nm^-1)" % (new_qy)

ax_lhs = f_lhs.add_subplot(111)
ax_lhs.format_coord = format_coord
```

Comment: Thanks I used the first method and it worked like a charm!